# 50 reputation option does not exist in the bounty offer drop down list

Tags: support, bounties

After I clicked the "start a bounty" link, in the drop down list, the 50 reputation option did not exist:

[image]

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, my bad. Just I'm referred the [bounty help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and I found _To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50)_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either had 1) already bountied that question for 50 reputation before, or 2) you have posted an answer to that question already. In those cases, [the minimum bounty is 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Note that in the second case, it [doesn't matter if that answer is deleted or not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369348/4751173); this is probably to prevent people from deleting the answer, posting a bounty, and then undeleting it.